# Entity Framework Core 7 not closing database connections

Tags: entity-framework-core, asp.net-core-6.0

Recently we found an issue in our production code in which connections to an EFC database weren't being closed, quickly leading to all connections being taken and the service going down, we found a solution to the problem, but I'm confused as to why it works, and what the correct way of doing this is.

The original code looks like this:

```cs
public partial class SalesContext : DbContext { ... }

public SalesContext FetchSalesContext(String fullConnStr)
{
    var opt = new DbContextOptionsBuilder<SalesContext>();

    SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(fullConnStr);
    connection.Open();
    opt.UseSqlServer(connection.Result);

    return new SalesContext(opt.Options);
}

public async Task<Sale> FetchSale(Guid salesId)
{
    using (var dbContext = FetchSalesContext())
    {
        Sale sale = await dbContext.Sales.FindAsync(salesId);
        if (sale != null)
            await dbContext.Entry(sale).Reference(prop => prop.Status).LoadAsync();
        
        return sale;
    }
}
```

So my understanding of this is that the dbContext defined in the using statement should be disposed at the end of the block, however that doesn't seem to be the case.  We fix this like this:

```cs
private void DisposeSalesContext(SalesContext salesContext)
{
    if (salesContext.Database.IsSqlServer())
        salesContext.Database.CloseConnection();
}

public async Task<Sale> FetchSale(Guid salesId)
{
    var dbContext = FetchSalesContext();

    try
    {
        Sale sale = await dbContext.Sales.FindAsync(salesId);
        if (sale != null)
            await dbContext.Entry(sale).Reference(prop => prop.Status).LoadAsync();
        
        return sale;
    }
    finally
    {
        DisposeSalesContext(dbContext);
    }
}
```

Which works just fine, but it feels like that's what the using statement should have been doing anyway.  What am I missing here?

Comment: It is a rule - do not dispose if you do not create. Why do you need to create and open connection manually?

Comment: Honestly I don't know, I'm not super familiar with the ins and outs of EF, and this is code that predates me, and was fixed by someone other than me.  I'm just trying to work out how it's supposed to work, currently it feels wrong

Comment: It works as expected. EF received SqlConnection which was not created by EF Core - so it is right that connection is not disposed.

Answer (score 0):

Is this code part of the same class or separate snippits from different classes? It looks a bit odd together.

The issue is that you are manually instantiating a database connection and telling the EF DbContext to use this connection rather than manage one itself.  This code looks like it is from a DbContext factory:

```
public SalesContext FetchSalesContext(String fullConnStr)
{
    var opt = new DbContextOptionsBuilder<SalesContext>();

    SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(fullConnStr);
    connection.Open();
    opt.UseSqlServer(connection.Result);

    return new SalesContext(opt.Options);
}
```

The simplest solution would be to allow EF to manage its own Connection as the above code does not appear to be managing any lifetime scope for the SQL Connection:

```
public SalesContext FetchSalesContext(String fullConnStr)
{
    return new SalesContext(fullConnStr);
}
```

where SalesContext has a constructor that accepts the connection string:

```
private readonly string _connectionString;

public SalesContext(string fullConnStr)
{
    ArgumentException.ThrowIfNullOrEmpty(fullConnStr, nameof(fullConnStr));
    _connectionString = fullConnStr;
}

 protected override void OnConfiguring(DbContextOptionsBuilder optionsBuilder)
{
    optionsBuilder.UseSqlServer(_connectionString);
}
```

There may be other options you want to initialize or standardize as well which can be passed in this way, or just initialized in the DbContext.

The method you have there with creating an `SqlConnection` would normally be done where the factory was going to take responsibility of the lifetime scope of the `SqlConnection` such as to share a single connection across `DbContext` instances. However something like that would be potentially problematic since it would be responsible for disposing of that `SqLConnection` or pool of connections, and should only do so after all of the `DbContext` instances that might be referencing them have been disposed. Since you are constructing an `SqlConnection` with each `DbContext` this isn't necessary.  The alternative fix for the existing code would be to implement a `Dispose` method and pattern within your SalesContext and on dispose, have it dispose of it's connection.

Rather than an explicit method that may be forgotten to be called:

```
private void DisposeSalesContext(SalesContext salesContext)
{
    if (salesContext.Database.IsSqlServer())
        salesContext.Database.CloseConnection();
}
```

the dispose pattern:

```
public void Dispose()
{
    Dispose(true);
    GC.SuppressFinalize(this);
}

protected virtual void Dispose(bool disposing)
{
    if (_disposed)
        return;

    if (disposing)
    {
        Database.CloseConnection();
    }

    _disposed = true;
}
```

This will work with `using` blocks to close the connection. Note that this is not necessary if you adjust the DbContextFactory to pass the connection string to the DbContext to initialize itself with. (Recommended) The DbContext will manage the lifetime scope of its underlying connection automatically. This also should not be done if sharing a DbConnection between DbContexts as one context disposing will close the shared connection.